# Issues integrating the Marketing Cloud Mobile Push Android SDK via Android Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to follow the steps to integrate the Marketing Cloud Mobile Push Android SDK via Android Studio (Journey Builder for Apps Android SDK v4.7.1) with an Android Mobile App. I'm using maven repository to include SFMC (`maven { url "http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/repository" }`).

I've found some issues with the version of dependencies required in the documentation. The current version of the mobile app is:

> API 15: Android 4.0.3 (IceCreamSandwich)
>
> - compileSdkVersion 25
> - buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

As dependencies required by Marketing Cloud Mobile Push Android SDK seems to be older than the mobile app project I had to create references to version 25. After that Android seems to compile all dependencies correctly but when I include the SFMC code existing in the step called *Configure the SDK* this code is not compiled because the compiler cannot find some classes (i.e. ETRequestStatus).

The following is the Firebase version currently used in the mobile app:

> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
>
> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'

I'm wondering if someone has also had this kind of errors and can guide me to find a solution for this.